# ADO.NET Entity Framework missing

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

I want to add Entity Framework to my project but for some reason the Item is missing. What do I do wrong? I´ve done this lika a 100 times before.

(I´ve tried by downloaded the nuget package, restarted my computer, created a new project and searched google.)

[image: ADO.NET Entity Framework missing]

Comment: What framework are you targeting? Try 4.5 or higher. Otherwise, have you installed EFTools.msi? http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/installing-ef-power-tools-into-vs2015/

Comment: @Steve Greene When you write "What framework are..." what do you mean by 'framework'? Do you mean the version of Entity Framework? At the moment, I have version 6.1.3 installed, which seems to be the latest.

Comment: No, sorry, what .NET framework does it target? If it is old you won't see the ADO.NET stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to Package Manager console and type:

```
install-package EntityFramework
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however, it doesn´t work. This is one of the things I tried before I asked this question. The thing is that I with my current computer, Visual Studio 2015 and Windows 10 has used Entity Framework many times, but all of a sudden, its missing.